# SQL statement to list and country countries in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a some rows like this in a table:

```
SWEDEN
MEXICO
USA
SWEDEN
GERMANY
RUSSIA
MEXICO
SWEDEN
```

Now I need to create a script to count the countries and list them like this:

```
Country    Amount of countries
SWEDEN        3
USA           1
MEXICO        2
RUSSIA        1
GERMANY       1
```

I'm stuck at:

```
SELECT Country
FROM dbo.Customers
```

How do I only show them once and create a row and count them?

Thanks a lot..

Comment: `COUNT()` -- is what you need.

Comment: Your question has absolutely nothing to do with C# or MySQL - don't just put random tags on questions please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
SELECT Country, count(*)
FROM dbo.Customers
group by Country
```

Comment: thanks! How do I add a where on the count? Let's say I only want to show countries occurring more then 1 time.

Comment: Check the HAVING clause

Comment: SELECT Country, count(*)
FROM dbo.Customers
group by Country HAVING count(*) > 1